# Any good tools to automate js script combining?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use visual studio 2010 for writing javascript and jquery. Are there any fast and easy ways to automate script combining? It doesn't have to be tied to Visual studio, any method that is simple and easy to setup will do.

THanks

Comment: What is "script combining?"  Do you want to produce a single script that executes as each of the inputs in series?   Do you want to ignore differences due to `var`s not being hoisted across script boundaries, or failures causing `window.onerror` and not preventing later scripts from running?

Answer (score 3):

[SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher)

The Friendly ASP.NET JavaScript and CSS Squisher

Answer (score 1):

Try [require.js](http://requirejs.org/). The nicest feature is that you can combine your dependency scripts at any point in your project lifecycle without any modifications required to your includes.

Comment: I've looked into this one and it seems that it doesn't combine them, but just loads them up differently. I think you also need to use some special pattern to use it effectively

Comment: It does combine them if you use their pipeline (see the optimize section in their docs: http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#optimize)

Comment: This seems kind of complicated. I am on a windows platform, but this seems more geared to linux tools

Comment: While there is a small learning curve to using the framework, it's very much worthwhile in the end. You should be able to run it fine on a Windows machine with a little investigation.

Comment: I finally was able to get requireJS to minify scripts, but how do I get it to combine them? Do my scripts need to be written using the module pattern for requireJS to combine them?

Answer (score 0):

Give [chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) a try, lot's of nice visual studio integration.  It will minify, uglify and mash them.  It also handle css, less and coffeescript.  Hopefully sass will be supported sometime soon ;-)